# Vmware ESXI 8.0 four of six VM guests are working with public IP each

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am reaching out to seek your assistance regarding a network connectivity issue we are facing after migrating our VMs from ESXi 6.7 to 8.0.

In our previous environment (ESXi 6.7), we had six Windows 10 VMs, each assigned with one public IP, and all were functioning properly.

After migrating to ESXi 8.0, we are encountering a problem where only four out of the six VMs are successfully connecting to the network with their respective public IPs.

Current configuration:

ESXi IP: 14x.xx.167.81

VM Assignments:

VM1: 14x.xx.167.82 (Working)

VM2: 14x.xx.167.83 (Working)

VM3: 14x.xx.167.84 (Working)

VM4: 14x.xx.167.85 (Working)

VM5: 14x.xx.167.86 (Not working; connects only when any of the above working VMs is turned off)

VM6: 14x.xx.167.87 (Not working; connects only when any of the above working VMs is turned off)

Our hosting provider has provided us with an IP range of 14 IPs, and our network details are as follows:

Gateway: 14x.xx.166.1

Usable IPs: 14x.xx.167.81 - 14x.xx.167.93

Broadcast: 14x.xx.167.255

Subnet mask: 255.255.254.0

All IPs are properly configured, and we have observed that when one of the working VMs is turned off, the non-functional VMs are able to connect to the network.

We appreciate your prompt attention to this matter and kindly request your expertise in identifying and resolving the connectivity issue.

Comment: Have you checked for mac address collisions?

Comment: Hello Gerald, Thank you for your response, we have checked the MAC Addresses for each vNIC adapter they are different. Also we removed all the vNICs and recreated and tried too, still the same issue. :-(

Comment: Is a distributed vSwitch involved? Are all VMs in the same port group? Is the number of ports in the port group limited?

Comment: If each VM is using 2 vCPU (so 2 vCPU/VM x 4 VM = 8 vCPU) that would coincide with using the free license rather than the full license or the evaluation mode. Random site with a screenshot: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/esxi-is-free-so-why-would-you-buy-an-esxi-anyway#fancy-image-1

Comment: @A.B that would result in not being able to turn the VMs on, not problems with network connectivity.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider ah right.

Comment: We have hosted this server With Velia.net and they have one NIC directly connected to Internet with Public IP. no fancy configuration vSwitch and the port group is VM network by default installed with ESXi same configuration is working fine with Esxi 6.7 but we tried with 7.0 and 8.0 same issue. only 4 VMS are connecting to network. we contacted the Velia support if any subnetting issue and they are confirmed no problem with subnetting we can confirm that if assign any random IP in the given rage in one of the 4 VMs they are connecting.

Comment: @AnandPoduri Could you look at how the ports are assigned on your switch/port group/s please, hopefully the switch is configured for a large number of ports (like 4096/8192 or similar) and the port groups are set to be elastic.

Comment: Hello @Chopper3, Here is the switch details.

MTU 1500
Ports 3200 (3180 available)
Link discovery Listen / Cisco discovery protocol (CDP)
Attached VMs 6 (6 active)
Beacon interval 1

But out of 6 only 4 VMs are connected network.

Comment: @AnandPoduri did you update the vmtools on the VMs after moving to v8? Not convinced that will help but you never know

Comment: Hello All, Thank you for support in resolving the issue. Finally we resolved the issue. The issue is with ISP switch port configuration is set to 4 MAC addresses that are allowed on a single physical port are limited. So we contacted the ISP to set the allowed MACs to 14 as per IP range. now all the network is up and all machines are connected NW.

Comment: So the 'all were functioning properly' was incorrect and this had nothing to do with vSphere 8???

Comment: @AnandPoduri please post this as an answer and accept it when you are allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

> we have observed that when one of the working VMs is turned off, the non-functional VMs are able to connect to the network.

That very much sounds like there are duplicate MAC addresses assigned to the VMs. Check their vNIC settings and either switch them to automatic if they aren't or manually set them so that no two are the same.

Comment: Hello Zac, Thank you for your response, we have checked the MAC Addresses for each vNIC adapter they are different. Also we removed all the vNICs and recreated and tried too, still the same issue. :-(